# How does the Python range function have a default parameter before the actual one?

Tags: python, range, default-value

I'm writing a function that takes an optional list and extends it to the length specified. Rather than writing it as `foo(n, list=None)` I was wondering how I might emulate the behavior of Python's range function which works like:

```
>>> range(10)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> range(5, 10)
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

That is, with the default parameter first. For reference trying to naively set this up returns a syntax error:

```
def foo(x=10, y):
    return x + y
SyntaxError: non-default argument follows default argument
```

So I'm wondering, is this hard-coded into range? Or can this behavior be emulated?

Comment: You could count the number of arguments.

Comment: @eryksun: I don't think this is very helpful in this case.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They aren't real keyword arguments.

If there's one argument, it's the limit.

If there are two arguments, the first is the start value and the second is the limit.

If there are three arguments, the first is the start value, the second is the limit, and the third is the stride.

Answer (score 12):

Others have shown how it can be done using argument counting. If I were to implement it myself in Python, though, I'd do it more like this.

```
def range(start, limit=None, stride=1):
    if limit is None:
        start, limit = 0, start
    # ...
```

Comment: +1 but this gives `TypeError: range() takes no keyword arguments`
`    for i in range(limit=len(A), stride=2):`

Comment: @Coder This defines a new range function, not uses the built-in one which would throw that error

Answer (score 8):

One way to write `range` in pure python would be

```
def range(*args):
    if len(args) > 3:
        raise TypeError, 'range expected at most 3 arguments, got %d' % len(args)
    if len(args) == 2:
        return range(args[0], args[1], 1)
    if len(args) == 1:
        return range(0, args[0], 1)
    else:
        # actual code for range(start, stop, step) here
```

Comment: Doesn't properly handle zero arguments.

Comment: Passing zero arguments is not allowed anyway, you'll get a "range expected 1 arguments, got 0". But for completeness you have a point, raising this error would be nice.

Answer (score 6):

Python implements `range()` by looking at the number of arguments. It shouldn't be too hard to write a Python version of this code

**from rangeobject.c:**

```
static PyObject *
range_new(PyTypeObject *type, PyObject *args, PyObject *kw)
{
    rangeobject *obj;
    long ilow = 0, ihigh = 0, istep = 1;
    unsigned long n;

    if (!_PyArg_NoKeywords("xrange()", kw))
        return NULL;

    if (PyTuple_Size(args) <= 1) {
        if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args,
                        "l;xrange() requires 1-3 int arguments",
                        &ihigh))
            return NULL;
    }
    else {
        if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args,
                        "ll|l;xrange() requires 1-3 int arguments",
                        &ilow, &ihigh, &istep))
            return NULL;
    }
    if (istep == 0) {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError, "xrange() arg 3 must not be zero");
        return NULL;
    }
    n = get_len_of_range(ilow, ihigh, istep);
    if (n > (unsigned long)LONG_MAX || (long)n > PY_SSIZE_T_MAX) {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_OverflowError,
                        "xrange() result has too many items");
        return NULL;
    }

    obj = PyObject_New(rangeobject, &PyRange_Type);
    if (obj == NULL)
        return NULL;
    obj->start = ilow;
    obj->len   = (long)n;
    obj->step  = istep;
    return (PyObject *) obj;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
def f(*args):
    nargs = len(args)
    if nargs == 1:
        start = 0
        end = args[0]
        step = 1
    elif nargs == 2:
        start = args[0]
        end = args[1]
        step = 1
    elif nargs == 3:
        start = args[0]
        end = args[1]
        step = args[2]
    else:
        raise TypeError('wrong number of arguments')

    return g(start, end, step)
```